# How do I open a locally installed wordpress on chrome

Tags: wordpress

Super basic noob question here.

What would be the file to open up on google chrome if I want to preview the wordpress site I'm building locally? The default.html is completely blank, and I'm not seeing an index.html or anything I can open

EDIT: What would be the php file to open/edit if I want to adjust the home page of the site?

Comment: The actually files are in the themes folder in wp-content

Answer (score 2):

You would have to first install a local web server. If you're on a Windows machine, something like WAMP or XAMPP will fit your needs to install Apache. From there, you'll install Wordpress by moving the wordpress files into the web directory (usually it's www or public_html) and then you'll be able to view the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need a local server to run wordpress or any php framework. I would recommend installing WAMP and upload your wordpress folder there, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You need a local server to run WordPress. You can use XAMPP that will fit both windows and Linux. Move your WordPress folder into installed xampp folder, like: c:/xampp/htdocs/'WordPress'.
Then open your browser and type localhost/wordpress and install WordPress.

If you want to write new .php files then you have to write that inside a theme as a template.